# Metpy Cross Section Geodesic

Tags: metpy

I may be asking the wrong question here, and am far from a matter expert, but when creating a cross section, is it possible to follow a rhumb line? The documentation states it takes a vertical cross-sectional slice along a geodesic through the given data on a regular grid. This seems to indicate it'll follow great circle.

Or, is this all a matter of having my data in a certain projection before calling the cross section method? If so, are there any facilities in Metpy for doing this? I've found some ideas on other SO searches.

These are the lat coordinates from one of my cross sections.
What I really want are the lats to stay they same.

```
From: (40.05, -80) lat, lon
To: (40.05, 20.06)

[40.05       40.49129217 40.92753221 41.35857652 41.78427825 42.20448739
 42.6190507  43.02781183 43.43061131 43.8272866  44.21767222 44.60159979
 44.97889817 45.34939353 45.71290958 46.06926767 46.41828699 46.75978478
 47.09357658 47.41947646 47.73729732 48.04685118 48.34794952 48.64040361
 48.92402495 49.19862562 49.46401872 49.72001885 49.96644255 50.20310884
 50.42983969 50.64646057 50.85280099 51.04869508 51.23398211 51.40850708
 51.5721213  51.72468292 51.86605751 51.99611856 52.11474806 52.22183695
 52.31728562 52.40100434 52.47291364 52.53294472 52.58103974 52.61715208
 52.64124659 52.65329974 52.65329974 52.64124659 52.61715208 52.58103974
 52.53294472 52.47291364 52.40100434 52.31728562 52.22183695 52.11474806
 51.99611856 51.86605751 51.72468292 51.5721213  51.40850708 51.23398211
 51.04869508 50.85280099 50.64646057 50.42983969 50.20310884 49.96644255
 49.72001885 49.46401872 49.19862562 48.92402495 48.64040361 48.34794952
 48.04685118 47.73729732 47.41947646 47.09357658 46.75978478 46.41828699
 46.06926767 45.71290958 45.34939353 44.97889817 44.60159979 44.21767222
 43.8272866  43.43061131 43.02781183 42.6190507  42.20448739 41.78427825
 41.35857652 40.92753221 40.49129217 40.05      ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MetPy's `cross_section`](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.interpolate.cross_section.html) currently only computes geodesic/great circle paths between starting and ending lat/lon points to use for the vertical cross section. To use an alternative path (such as a rhumb line), the underlying [`interpolate_to_slice`](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.interpolate.interpolate_to_slice.html) function can be used with an array of points in the horizontal dimension coordinates of your dataset. For instance, assuming your data are in 1D lat/lon coordinates (i.e., equirectangular projection), your example becomes

```py
start_lat, start_lon = (40.05, -80)
end_lat, end_lon = (40.05, 20.06)
n_points = 100

lats = np.linspace(start_lat, end_lat, n_points)
lons = np.linspace(start_lon, end_lon, n_points)

cross = interpolate_to_slice(data, np.stack([lons, lats], axis=1))
```

If your data are on some other projection, you will need to obtain the properly transformed coordinates and use those instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the way I need to do it, but am struggling with getting my data parsed correctly for this method, and when I do, it seems I'm missing some accessor method (not all of them). Maybe my version isn't quite right.  The cross_section method succeeds, but this one doesn't quite, some units issue. If I get this working, I'll update my answer with something more detailed.